# How to use view logic to determine a component's props

Tags: reactjs

I have this component which in some cases I want to give a `value` and an `onChange` prop, specifically when an id prop is passed to the component.

```
<TextField
    hintText="Recipe Name"
    ref={r => this.recipeName = r}
    {this.props.id ? 'value={this.state.name}' : ''}
    {this.props.id ? 'onChange={this.handleNameChange}' : ''} />
```

However, I get this error when I use this code.

```
BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (71:13)

  69 |             hintText="Recipe Name"
  70 |             ref={r => this.recipeName = r}
> 71 |             {this.props.id ? 'value={this.state.name}' : ''}
     |              ^
  72 |             {this.props.id ? 'onChange={this.handleNameChange}' : ''} />
```

I know just putting the view logic outside of the component works fine, like this:

```
{ this.props.id ?
    <TextField
        hintText="Recipe Name"
        ref={r => this.recipeName = r}
        value={this.state.name}
        onChange={this.handleNameChange}/> :
      <TextField
        hintText="Recipe Name"
        ref={r => this.recipeName = r} />
}
```

But because I'm using multiple `<TextField />` components, this code is getting really clunky. Is there any way that I could use the `? :` view logic inside the components props instead of outside?

Answer (score 1):

you may try it like below,

```
<TextField
  hintText="Recipe Name"
  ref={r => this.recipeName = r}
  value = {this.props.id ? this.state.name : undefined} // no need to use curly braces inside another curly brace
  onChange = {this.props.id ? this.handleNameChange : undefined} 
/>
```

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting the same error with the BabelLoader

Answer (score 1):

Messing around with Ahmmed's code I found out that by setting the else condition of the terniary operator to `undefined`, it would be as if the prop values `value` and `onChange` were never set. This code doesn't throw any errors and saved me a lot of typing:

```
<TextField
      hintText="Recipe Name"
      ref={r => this.recipeName = r}
      value = {this.props.id ? this.state.name : undefined}
      onChange = {this.props.id ? this.handleNameChange : undefined} />
```